# Product of two hypergeometric functions

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

Is there any formula that gives the following specific product of two Hypergeometric functions
$$_2 F_1(\alpha, \alpha+1 ; m ; z)\, _2 F_1(\alpha, \alpha+1 ; n ; z)\, , $$
for $m, n $ positive integers and $\alpha$ a positive half integer?

I am aware of the general formula in terms of a sum of $_4 F_3$'s, but I am looking for a formula that contains just a single $_p F_q$ which should exist according to "Higher Transcendental Functions, Vol. 1" by A. Erdelyi page 185.

P.S.

There is some physics behind this problem. It is a piece of a kernel in the energy basis arising in the study of a problem in Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: If $m=n$ you can express the product in terms of the Appell $F_4$ function. See here for more details: https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.0655

Answer (score 1):

If you allow some relation between $m$ and $n$, then it is possible.

Let $m+n=2\alpha+2$. Then
\begin{align}
&_2 F_1(\alpha, \alpha+1 ; m ; z)\, _2 F_1(\alpha, \alpha+1 ; n ; z) \\
=&\,\,_4F_3(\alpha,\alpha+1,\alpha+\frac12,\alpha+1;2\alpha+1,m,2\alpha-m;4z(1-z)).\end{align}

Comment: I still think a more general formula should exist... Also why the downvote??